# Errors running remote powershell script with PsEcec.exe

Tags: powershell, remote-server, psexec

I have a powershell script on a remote windows box that finds the folder pointed to by a junction. The contents of the script looks like this:

```
return fsutil reparsepoint query C:\foo\bar\junction_name | where-object { $_ -imatch 'Print Name:' } | foreach-object { $_ -replace 'Print Name\:\s*','' }
```

When I run this on the remote box, it executes as expected :)

However, when I try to run this remotely from my local machine:

```
C:\Users\foo>C:\pstools\PsExec.exe \\remote_server_name "powershell D:\bar\my_script.ps1"
```

I get errors:

> PsExec could not start powershell D:\bar\my_script.ps1 on
>   remote_server_name: The filename, directory name, or volume label
>   syntax is incorrect.

Any ideas what this error is telling me (given that I can run the script directly on the remote box with no issues)?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the following to work:

```
PsExec.exe \\remote_server_name powershell.exe D:\bar\my_script.ps1
```

However, the powershell session did not close as expected and remained in a hanging state after my script returned so calling it via `cmd` as detailed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/437504/why-does-psexec-hang-after-successfully-running-a-powershell-script) seems to fix that:

```
PsExec.exe \\remote_server_name cmd /c "echo . | powershell.exe D:\bar\my_script.ps1"
```

Thanks for all of the suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

1- maybe you should avoid psexec and take advantage of powershell remoting

```
invoke-command -computername remote_server_name -scriptblock {. "D:\bar\my_script.ps1"}
```

2- if you want to keep psexec, look at the starting directory switch `-w`

```
PsExec.exe \\remote_server_name -w D:\bar "powershell -file my_script.ps1"
```

Comment: Thanks, Kayasax. I can't use ps remoting because it requires a firewall which I can't have in my environment. With the second option, it still complains of not being able to find the file specified...

Comment: d:\bar is a path on the remote host right ? please try the following command "powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -file my_script.ps1"

Comment: Yes, that's that path alright. I tried your suggestion (`PsExec.exe \\remote_server_name -w D:\bar "powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file my_script.ps1"`) and got the same result (can't find the file). However, this hack kind of worked: `"PsExec.exe \\remote_server_name cmd /c "powershell D:\bar\my_script.ps1"`... but the process doesn't complete...

Comment: yes, the command should be like `PsExec.exe \\remote_server_name -w D:\bar powershell.exe " -file my_script.ps1"`

Comment: That gave the same issue (can't find the file) - so then I did this: `PsExec.exe \\remote_server_name -w D:\bar cmd /c "echo %cd%"` to print the directory after the `-w` command and surprisingly it print my *local* home directory - not the remote one? (Maybe I just misunderstand what `-w` does)

Comment: no this must be the remote dir. From the doc "-w directory Set the working directory of the process (relative to the remote computer). "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90864/discussion-between-pat-mustard-and-kayasax).

Answer (score 1):

PS Remoting would be the best way to go here and I'd actually put up a good fight for opening up TCP/5985 on your machines. The minuscule security risk is, by far, worth the management benefits you'll get with it.

Worst case scenario use the WMI Win32_Process class. Something like this might work.

```
$wmiParams = @{
    'ComputerName' = 'Somecomputer'
    'Class' = 'Win32_Process'
    'Name' = 'Create'
    'Args' = 'fsutil reparsepoint query C:\foo\bar\junction_name > C:\temp.txt'
}
Invoke-WmiMethod @wmiParams
Get-Content \\somecomputer\c$\temp.txt | where-object { $_ -imatch 'Print Name:' } | foreach-object { $_ -replace 'Print Name\:\s*', '' }
```